# Query improvement runs slowly

Tags: mysql

I have a query which I don't see how I can optimize, however maybe someone has some insight into it.

Here is my table:

```
      comments
        ---------
            +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
            | Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
            +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
            | commentid   | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
            | parentid    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | refno       | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | createdate  | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
            | remoteip    | varchar(80)   | YES  |     |         |                |
            | fingerprint | varchar(50)   | YES  |     |         |                |
            | locid       | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
            | clubid      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | profileid   | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
            | userid      | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
            | global      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | official    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | legacyuser  | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
            | mediaid     | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | status      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
            | comment     | varchar(4000) | YES  |     |         |                |
            | likes       | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | dislikes    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | import      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
            | author      | varchar(50)   | YES  |     |         |                |
            +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is my table explain:

```
        | comments | CREATE TABLE `comments` (
      `commentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `refno` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `createdate` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `remoteip` varchar(80) DEFAULT '',
      `fingerprint` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
      `locid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `clubid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `profileid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `userid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `global` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `official` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `legacyuser` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `mediaid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
      `comment` varchar(4000) DEFAULT '',
      `likes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `dislikes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `import` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `author` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`commentid`),
      KEY `comments_locid` (`locid`),
      KEY `comments_userid` (`userid`),
      KEY `idx_legacyusers` (`legacyuser`),
      KEY `profile_index` (`profileid`),
      KEY `comments_createdate` (`createdate`),
      KEY `compound_for_comments` (`locid`,`global`,`status`),
      KEY `global` (`global`),
      KEY `status` (`status`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3848451 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And finally, here is my query:

```
SELECT c.createdate commentdate 
  FROM comments c
 WHERE status > 0 
   AND locid 
    IN 
     ( SELECT locid 
         FROM locations 
        WHERE state = 'NJ'
     ) 
 ORDER 
    BY c.createdate DESC 
 LIMIT 15
```

**There are indexes on locid and state for the subquery**

As you can see there is a subselect against the locations table to formulate the `locids` to be used for the outer query.

Hopefully there is some room for improvements.

Comment: your subquery can probably be rewritten as a regular `join`...

Comment: One step would be to remove " * ". Also, while I appreciate that JOINs appear no longer to be fashionable, there was a time when performance benefits could be extracted from them.

Comment: Can we see CREATE table statements for BOTH tables. And the EXPLAIN for the query

Answer (score 0):

This could be equivalent and probably a bit faster .

```
select *,comments.createdate as commentdate 
from comments FORCE INDEX (locid_status)
inner join locations FORCE INDEX (your_index_name) on (comments.locid  = locations.locid and locations.state='NJ')
where comments.status>0 
order by comments.createdate desc limit 15
```

Comment: It did not improve very much. ~0.5 seconds faster.

Comment: how many record ?  then you need and index on scx_comments  (locid) and one on scl_locations(.locid)

Comment: I have indexes on these columns. Theres approx 2.5 million records in the database.

Comment: You have a composite  index on locid and status in scx_comments ?

Comment: and a composite index on locid and  state in locations ?

Comment: That's a no for both

Comment: If you need an improvement you should evaluate the composite index using  the most selective column as first and the other as second and so on ..

Comment: Just for curiosity how many seconds or minutes  run the query .. ?

Comment: Its taking 6 seconds.

Comment: with right composite index you can improve ... your query performance

Comment: I added the indexes and its produced a small increase (~0.5 sec faster)

Comment: Is this what you mean by a composite index: alter table comments add index `locid_status` (`locid`,`status`);

Comment: yes ..but the improvement is too small ... you tried also the second .. index

Comment: and have you removed the single index?

Comment: i dont think i can do that. there are other queries that use single index

Comment: then the composite  composite are unuseful   or you must  impose/force the use of the composite index ..

Comment: doesnt seem to do much.

Comment: thanks for trying although it did not seem to do much improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If locations is a small table join it directly is faster than using a sub query.

```
select *,comments.createdate as commentdate 
from comments as c, locations as l 
where status > 0 
and l.state = 'NJ'
and l.locid = c.locid
order by c.createdate desc limit 15;
```